# compareTo two generic types

Tags: java, generics

I would like to make a generic binairy tree, however I am having some problems figuring out why I can't compare two values of generic types.

```
public class Node <E extends Comparable<E> > implements Comparable<Node>  {

private E value;
public Node(E value){
    this.value = value;
}

public E getValue() {
    return value;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Node o) {

    int a = value.compareTo(o.getValue()));
    return a;
}
```

I keep getting a error with the line : value.compareTo(o.getValue()) .
It says I have to Cast o.getValue to type E however it is already from type E ?

How would I be able to solve this ? I have tried makeig value Comparable, but this still doesn't solve my problem.

thx

Thx

Edit: solved by doing :
It should be public int compareTo(Node o) and implements Comparable>

Comment: It should be `public int compareTo(Node<E> o)` and `implements Comparable<Node<E>>`

Comment: yup , this solved it, I had to change the interface to Comparable<Node<E>> to make it work, thx very much.

Comment: In English, that is: a Node is not comparable to all Nodes (the raw type), but only to Nodes of the same type as itself. A `List<Apple>` should not be comparable to `List` because then it can be compared to `List<Orange>`. A `List<Apple>` should be comparable to other `List<Apple>`s.